# Change amCharts XYCharts column colors based on json property value

Tags: javascript, json, charts, amcharts, amcharts4

I would like to change amCharts XYCharts column (or category or series) color based on the value on the json data.

```js
am4core.ready(function() {

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "country": "USA",
  "visits": 2125,
  "color": "#333333"
}, {
  "country": "China",
  "visits": 2122,
  "color": "#FA0152"
}];

// Create axes

var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "country";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;

categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("dy", function(dy, target) {
  if (target.dataItem && target.dataItem.index & 2 == 2) {
    return dy + 25;
  }
  return dy;
});

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "visits";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "country";
series.name = "Visits";
series.columns.template.tooltipText = "{categoryX}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
series.columns.template.fillOpacity = .8;

var columnTemplate = series.columns.template;
columnTemplate.strokeWidth = 2;
columnTemplate.strokeOpacity = 1;

}); // end am4core.ready()
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Resources -->
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

My JSON data is:

```
[{
  "country": "USA",
  "visits": 2125,
  "color": "#333333"
}, {
  "country": "China",
  "visits": 2122,
  "color": "#FA0152"
}]
```

I want a column of the chart should have color as per JSON property "color". Any help or idea would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an `adapter` function to change column color run time. See my updated answer for your need.

```js
am4core.ready(function() {

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "country": "USA",
  "visits": 2125,
  "color": "#333333"
}, {
  "country": "China",
  "visits": 2122,
  "color": "#FA0152"
}];

// Create axes

var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "country";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;

categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("dy", function(dy, target) {
  if (target.dataItem && target.dataItem.index & 2 == 2) {
    return dy + 25;
  }
  return dy;
});

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "visits";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "country";
series.name = "Visits";
series.columns.template.tooltipText = "{categoryX}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
series.columns.template.fillOpacity = .8;
    series.columns.template.adapter.add("fill", function (fill, target) {
        return target.dataItem.dataContext["color"];
    });
    series.columns.template.adapter.add("stroke", function (fill, target) {
        return target.dataItem.dataContext["color"];
    });

var columnTemplate = series.columns.template;
columnTemplate.strokeWidth = 2;
columnTemplate.strokeOpacity = 1;

}); // end am4core.ready()
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Resources -->
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Works charmingly.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function drawChart(ChartType) {
  var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.PieChart3D);
  am4core.ready(function () {
  // Themes begin
  am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
});
if (ChartType == 'P') {
  chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.PieChart3D);
  chart.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0; // this creates initial fade-in

  chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
}
else {
  if (ChartType == 'B') {
  chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
  }
}
      
chart.data = [
{
country: "India",
match: 421,
color: "#00F"
},
{
country: "WestIndies",
match: 56,
color: "#F00"
},
{
country: "Ireland",
match: 201,
color: "#0FF"
},
{
country: "Germany",
match: 165,
color: "#c2c2c2"
}
];

if (ChartType == 'P') {
    var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries3D());
    series.dataFields.value = "match";
    series.dataFields.category = "country";

}
else if (ChartType == 'B') {

    var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
    categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
    categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "country";

    categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 60;
    categoryAxis.renderer.inversed = true;
    categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;

    var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
    valueAxis.min = 0;
    valueAxis.extraMax = 0.1;

    var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
    series.dataFields.categoryX = "country";
    series.dataFields.valueY = "match";

    series.tooltipText = "{valueX.value}"
    series.columns.template.strokeOpacity = 0;
    series.columns.template.column.cornerRadiusTopRight = 10;
    series.columns.template.column.cornerRadiusTopLeft = 10;

    var labelBullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
    labelBullet.label.verticalCenter = "bottom";
    labelBullet.label.dy = -10;
    labelBullet.label.text = "{values.valueY.workingValue.formatNumber('#.')}";

    chart.zoomOutButton.disabled = true;

    series.columns.template.adapter.add("fill", function (fill, target) {
        //return chart.colors.getIndex(target.dataItem.index);
        // Default color
        return target.dataItem.dataContext["color"];
        // custom color
    });

    categoryAxis.sortBySeries = series;
}
}
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
/* in case of non visibility of grid in map*/
path {
        stroke-dasharray: 1;
        stroke-dashoffset: 1;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<body>
<!-- HTML -->
<input type="button" value="3D Pie Chart" onclick="drawChart('P')" />
<input type="button" value="Horizental Bar Chart" onclick="drawChart('B')" />
<div id="chartdiv">
</div>

</body>
```